Collect Application Logs from App running on Azure VM
I am asked to design an solution in Azure where our application is running as docker container using docker compose on an Azure VM(Ubuntu).
The application logs to the stdout and the requirement is to collect these stdout log, push it to Azure and be able to view it in the Azure console.
We thought of using the Azure Monitor Agent(AMA) to do this but we are not able to find any documentation that points out to collecting logs from stdout.
We also thought of writing the logs to a log file and collect these logs for which there is enough documentation available, but in this approach we don't want to have the burden of burden of rotating the log file.
We need a solution that would pick the logs from stdout and forward them to azure console.
We Want to use only cloud native solutions as we don't want to have separate instance for running ELK stack or Grafana etc.
Also we don't want to use any client library as we deploy our application across the cloud platforms(Azure,AWS,GCP) and want to keep our codebase same across platforms

Azure Monitor Agent (AMA) doesn't natively capture stdout from containers. However, you can configure Docker to log to a file and have AMA collect those logs. Since you prefer not to handle log rotation, you can configure Docker to use a logging driver that handles rotation for you. Also check these out-    Monitoring in Azure Kubernetes Services


Tutorial: Monitor Windows containers on Service Fabric using Azure Monitor logs
Monitor logs in Azure Container Apps with Log Analytics


Hi @Arko Thanks for your inputs. The documentation you provided indicates to use Log Analytics Agent which will be deprecated by August 2024 and suggests to use AMA. So does the AMA also have the same capabilities to collect the container logs as the Log Analytics Agent

To collect logs from stdout of your application running in a Docker container on an Azure VM and view them in the Azure console without using additional third-party services or client libraries, you can use Azure Monitor with the Log Analytics Agent (formerly known as the Azure Monitor Agent or AMA). Despite its deprecation, Log Analytics Agent still supports collecting logs from Docker containers and pushing them to Azure Monitor.
Install the Log Analytics Agent on your Azure VM
for windows VM
for Linux VM
Create a Log Analytics Workspace in Azure. This workspace will be used to store and analyze your logs.
az monitor log-analytics workspace create --resource-group <your-resource-group> --workspace-name <your-workspace-name> --location <your-region>


Configure Docker to Log to a File- Edit your Docker daemon configuration file (usually found at /etc/docker/daemon.json on Linux) to ensure that logs are stored in a way that the Log Analytics Agent can read them
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3"
  }
}

Configure the Log Analytics Agent to Monitor Docker Log Files
The agent configuration will depend on whether you're using Windows or Linux. Here I will be using Linux where the agent configuration file is typically located at /etc/opt/microsoft/omsagent/conf/omsagent.d/
Create a new file containerlogs.conf in this directory
<source>
  type tail
  path /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  pos_file /var/opt/microsoft/omsagent/run/containers.log.pos
  tag oms.container.log.*
  format json
  read_from_head true
</source>

For windows,

Docker logs are located in C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers\<container_id>\<container_id>-json.log. adjust the agent configuration to monitor accordingly

Set up data Collection rule accordingly in your workspace. Point it to collect logs from the paths you've set up in your agent configuration.

Once done, use the Log Analytics query tool in the Azure portal to run a query to check the latest 10 log entries from your containers to ensure logs are being collected.
ContainerLog
| limit 10

By the way, make sure that network and firewall settings allow the VM to communicate with Azure Monitor.
